# Dualboot help- windows stuck on windows loading when i try to boot it, ubuntu 13.10 works fine though

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I installed ubuntu 13.10 the other day, and now when ever i try to get back into windows it keeps getting stuck at windows starting and the windows animation is still working, but it never loads. I tried to repair it has in the start up option for it, and it said the volume was corrupt. 
when i installed ubuntu though i made sure to have a mount / et4 (or whatever it was) and some free space for swap. I followed instructions as had been made on an installation guide. (knew i should of went with first option in installing ubuntu alongside windows by dual boot in installer). Now i'm wondering as to what can i do to atleast save my files from there and if there is a way of repairing it without losing all data on windows.

Answer (score 0):

## Reinstall grub

First of all you should be able to mount you' re Windows partition from Ubuntu to save you're data. To make you're Windows boot again I would boot the Windows recovery CD or the normal install CD and reinstall the Windows boot loader(there are instructions for all Windows versions just search in google). Then Windows should be bootable but you will have lost you're dual boot. Then reinstall then

Option 1: Find a bootable disk for reinstalling grub.

Option 2:Ubuntu and place the GRUB boot loader at the right place by clicking "something else" in the Ubuntu installation when it gets to partitioning and select the right place for the boot loader. Know you should be able to choose what you want to boot on start up.

Note 1: There are several instructions for the stuff above on the internet if you get stuck.

Note 2 :I'll maybe be able to give more help if you tell me which version of Windows you have.

Comment: Im using windows 7. so pretty much what you are saying is to reinstall both windows and ubuntu? i dont care much for windows its just i have some files on there which i need. so as long as i can get access to them like you said i should be fine. also, can increase my partition for ubuntu? after i get what i need i wanna transfer the whole windows partition and place the some 320gb into the ubuntu partition

Comment: Well you can fix you're boot loader with a Windows 7 CD but then you wont be able to start up Ubuntu any more because it will overwrite the Grub boot loader. If you don't need Windows but only you're files you can just copy them within Ubuntu. There are several easy instructions on the internet on how to partition you're Hard drive manually so do that and you are free in what you want to do next.